# Sorting the arrays of a 2d array between them

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array and i want to sort the 1d arrays in descending order. I dont think i can properly explain so here's an example.
I want to turn this:

```
3 5 6 7 8
1 2 4 9 10
1 3 5 6 10
```

Into this:

```
1 2 4 9 10
1 3 5 6 10
3 5 6 7 8
```

but i just cant get it right. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

intAlloc function just does a malloc and a check for if the allocation went right.
cpyArray coppies whatever is on the second arguement to the first and ANA is the number of elements the array in the first arguement has.

```
int **sortArray2(int **arr,int r,int c)
{
    int k,i,j,tmp;
    int *ptmp;
    ptmp = intAlloc(ANA);
//this part is just for sorting the numbers in each 1d array
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c-1; j++)
        {
            for(k=j+1; k<c; k++)
            {
                if(*(*(arr + i) + j) > *(*(arr + i)+ k))
                {
                    tmp = *(*(arr + i) + j);
                    *(*(arr + i) + j) = *(*(arr + i)+ k);
                    *(*(arr + i)+ k) = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//this is the part where im trying to do what i explain 
    for(i=0; i<r-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {   
            if(*(*(arr + i) + j) > *(*(arr + i+1)+ j))
            {
                cpyArray(ptmp, *(arr + i), ANA);
                cpyArray(*(arr + i), *(arr + i+1), ANA);
                cpyArray(*(arr + i),ptmp ,ANA);
                break;
                
            }
        }
    }
    free(ptmp);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why not `qsort`?

Comment: It seems that you are mixing comparison and swapping for the rows. You should compare, then swap whole rows, but you try to swap individual entries, which changes the rows. (Also, if you really have a ragged array of type `int **`, you don't need to copy the contents. It is enough to swap the pointers.)

Comment: I take it some prof mandated you not use subscript operators for otherwise-pointless reasons. Regardless, the only tmp that should be required to do this is a single `int*` when swapping rows, and it should *not* require using `intAlloc`. Therefore you're making things harder than they need be.

Comment: @KamilCuk given the confines of what the OP has available, how do you propose they deliver the column count `c` to `qsort` when it's sorting one level of indirection *higher* on rows? E.g. `qsort(arr, r, sizeof *arr, some_cmp)`, where `some_cmp` is eventually going to get the addresses of row pointers. How does `some_cmp` know how many cells are in each row?

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed, that's an usual problem - solved either with a global variable or with `qsort_r`.